# Python class method run when another method is invoked

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have a class as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.bar = "bar"
        self.methodCalls = 0  #tracks number of times any function in the instance is run

    def get_foo(self):
        addMethodCall()
        return self.foo

    def get_bar(self):
        addMethodCall()
        return self.bar

    def addMethodCall(self):
        self.methodCalls += 1
```

Is there an inbuilt function that is invoked whenever a method is invoked instead of constantly running `addMethodCall()`?

Comment: Methods are attributes too, and `__getattr__` is only accessed when an attribute is *missing*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will refine the question and find a better example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Question refined.

Comment: You could hook into `__getattribute__`, but I would think a decorator `@count_calls` on the methods you want to track would be a neater solution.

Comment: `__getattribute__` is accessed for *all* attribute access. You probably need to clean up your terminology; a *class method* is a `@classmethod`-decorated descriptor. Are you talking about *regular* methods here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Regular methods - I mean `foobar.addMethodCall()` - just a function inside the class.

Comment: Those are not class methods, those are just methods; you are trying to count method calls *per instance* here I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am trying to count the total amount of times that `get_foo()` and `get_bar()` have been called in a specific instance of the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters __gettattr__ was a bad example

Comment: using getattribute with callable() you could have the counter increment only on method calls or directly with an if at the name passed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there are no hooks *on a class* to do this. Methods are attributes *too*, albeit somewhat special in that they are produced when accessing the function object on the instance; functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

The *call* to a method object is then a separate step from producing the method object:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'bar method on Foo'
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x100777bd0>>
>>> f.bar is f.bar
False
>>> stored = f.bar
>>> stored()
'bar method on Foo'
```

It is the task of the [`object.__getattribute__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) to invoke the descriptor protocol, so you could hook into that to see when a method is produced, but you'd still need to *wrap* that produced method object to detect *calls*. You could return an object with a [`__call__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) that proxies for the actual method for example.

However, it'd be easier to decorate each method with a decorator that increments a counter every time it is called. Take into account decorators apply to a function *before* it is bound, so you'll have to pass `self` along:

```
from functools import wraps

def method_counter(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.methodCalls += 1
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

You'd still need to apply this to all functions in your class. You could apply this manually to all methods you want to count:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.bar = "bar"
        self.methodCalls = 0  #tracks number of times any function method is run

    @method_counter
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo

    @method_counter
    def get_bar(self):
        return self.bar
```

or you could use a metaclass:

```
import types

class MethodCounterMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, body):
        # create new class object
        for name, obj in body.items():
            if name[:2] == name[-2:] == '__':
                # skip special method names like __init__
                continue
            if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
                # decorate all functions
                body[name] = method_counter(obj)
        return super(MethodCounterMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, body)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # create a new instance for this class
        # add in `methodCalls` attribute
        instance = super(MethodCounterMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance.methodCalls = 0
        return instance
```

This takes care of everything the decorator needs, setting a `methodCalls` attribute for you, so your class doesn't have to:

```
class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MethodCounterMeta
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.bar = "bar"

    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo

    def get_bar(self):
        return self.bar
```

Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     __metaclass__ = MethodCounterMeta
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.foo = "foo"
...         self.bar = "bar"
...     def get_foo(self):
...         return self.foo
...     def get_bar(self):
...         return self.bar
...
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.get_foo()
'foo'
>>> instance.get_bar()
'bar'
>>> instance.methodCalls
2
```

The above metaclass only considers *function objects* (so the result of `def` statements and `lambda` expressions) part of the class body for decoration. It ignores any other callable objects (there are more types that have a `__call__` method, such as `functools.partial` objects), as are functions added to the class *later on*.

Comment: i disagree with the no hooks statement, it is perfectly possible to do so

Comment: @Mixone: there are no *direct hooks on a class*. You need to understand how methods are created and how calling those objects work instead.

Comment: @Mixone Either way it answers my question perfectly. Also I assume the modifier for special methods is optional?

Comment: @techydesigner: it is; otherwise the `__init__` method is counted too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ..and if `__init__` was actually called, would it return an error?

Comment: @techydesigner: no, it would not. `__init__` is just another method in this regard.

Comment: No i disagree with the answer in the sense that you state that one cannot hook into it, any method is an attribute and any method is callable, therefore if I call object.__getattribute__ I can get the correct functioning of the internal method and verify if the attribute is callable, a mix of both gives exactly what the questioneer needs in about 5 lines of code

Comment: @Mixone: then *post that as an answer*. But just testing that something is *callable* doesn't mean it'll actually *be* called.

Comment: @Mixone: So write your solution and post your own answer.

Comment: @Mixone: thanks for at least posting that as an answer; I'm sorry you felt you had to delete it. The approach did have huge flaws, you were counting attribute access (filtered on callable objects), not calls. In my answer here I did show why that distinction is important.

Comment: I felt like I had to delete it because as you said I forgot to take those things into account ^^ (took long to answer sorry, was busy)