# Using decorator in class method and populate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code and I have a dictionary where the key is any string, and the value is a function.  I then loop through each key in the dictionary and call the functions, like so:

```
class SomeClass:

    dictionary = {}

    # Not sure how to use this decorator function
    def decorator(key):
        def wrapper(funct):
            self.dictionary[key] = funct
            return funct
        return wrapper


    @decorator("some_val1")
    def function_1(self):
       ...

    @decorator("some_val2")
    def function_2(self):
       ...

    @decorator("some_val3")
    def function_3(self):
       ...

    def execute_all_functions(self):
        for key, _ in self.dictionary.items():
            self.dictionary[key]()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sclass = SomeClass()
    sclass.execute_all_functions()
```

So this should populate `dictionary` with:

```
{
   "some_val1": function_1(),
   "some_val2": function_2(),
   "some_val3": function_3()
}
```

I'm getting this error though

```
self.dictionary[key] = funct
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How would I be able to do this.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `self,` to the definitions of `decorator` and `wrapper` within the class? `def decorator(self,key):`, `def wrapper(self,funct):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

First you should read this: https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/descriptor.html , to know the difference of function vs method.

In your code, the key equals `self` of a method.

```
def decorator(key):
    def wrapper(funct):
        self.dictionary[key] = funct
        return funct
    return wrapper
```

If you want to use a class's property, you should refer by `cls`. Correct code might be:

```
@classmethod
def decorator(cls, key):
    def wrapper(funct):
        self.dictionary[key] = funct
        return funct
    return wrapper
```

So let's say if you want to update a class property, you must have `cls` reference. I have tried the code below, make the `decorator_maker` a classmethod.

```
class SomeClass:

    dictionary = {}

    @classmethod
    def decorator_maker(cls, key):
        print(cls, key)
        def decorator(funct):
            cls.dictionary[key] = funct
            return funct
        return decorator

    @decorator_maker("some_val1")
    def function_1(self):
       ...

    @decorator_maker("some_val2")
    def function_2(self):
       ...

    @decorator_maker("some_val3")
    def function_3(self):
       ...

    def execute_all_functions(self):
        for key, _ in self.dictionary.items():
            self.dictionary[key]()
```

And you will get an error like `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable`. Same as this question: ['classmethod' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058686/classmethod-object-is-not-callable). AKA, you can't call a classmethod until the class is defined.

So you may want to make the decorator outside the class. But for the same reason, you can't get a reference of `cls` until the classmethod. `method` is also an attribute of class, you can't dynamic change an attribute while define another. see [Python class method run when another method is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832228/python-class-method-run-when-another-method-is-invoked).

It would be easier if you move `dictionary` outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

`functools.wraps` might be useful. In the bellow trivial example, without `wraps` the decorator will not function correctly.

```
from functools import wraps

class SomeClass:
    var = 1

    @wraps
    def decorator(self, fn):
        return fn

    @decorator
    def return_value(self):
        print(self.var)
        return self.var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sclass = SomeClass()
    sclass.return_value()
```

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is accessing `dictionary` in the decorator and the fact that when I run `execute_all_functions`, `dictionary` is still empty.  So it seems like the `dictionary` variable never gets updated

Comment: The problem seems to be that your decorator can't see class variables, i.e. `self` is not recognised.

Comment: I think the key is let your decorator has a `cls` variable. Tried last night but it wouldn't work : (